# Validate the input using a while loop

Tags: java

I doing a little practice on Computer Science because when I leave the military I want to start taking classes on the basics of java. I'm a little stuck on this question i was wondering if i can get some assistance.

a program that allows the user to enter a character.  The only valid values are 'A', 'M', and 'S'.  Validate the input using a while loop so that if the user enters any value other than one of those 3 characters, an error message is displayed and the user is prompted for another value.  Once the user has finally entered valid data, print the character they entered back to the screen.

Comment: Can you post what you have attempted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into this basic example

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Read {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean isCheck = true;
        while (isCheck) {
            String str = sc.next();
            switch (str) {
                case "A":
                    System.out.println("A");
                    isCheck = false;
                    break;
                case "M":
                    System.out.println("M");
                    isCheck = false;
                    break;
                case "S":
                    System.out.println("S");
                    isCheck = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Not Valid : Enter next");
                    isCheck = true;

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank You very much Happy Holidays

Answer (score 0):

Reading you input within the loop will enforce repetitive reading of input.

```
public class Read {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean isCheck = true;
        while(isCheck){
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String str = sc.next();
            switch (str) {
                case "A":
                    System.out.println("A");
                    isCheck = false;
                    break;
                case "M":
                    System.out.println("M");
                    isCheck = false;
                    break;
                case "S":
                    System.out.println("S");
                    isCheck = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Not Valid : Enter next.");
                    isCheck = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much Happy Holidays